# JQuery File Upload Demo - для созданных динамически контейнеров

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ajax возвращает html c блоком `div#upload` для загрузки файлов с помощью **jQuery File Upload**.
Соответственно ничего не работает...

Кто знает, как решить эту проблему, нужен .on, .live
Ссылка на источник: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: > как решить эту проблему, нужен .on

 нужен .on

Comment: проблема в том, что не срабатывает событие для ajax возвращенного контента